# how to get value from map by position in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
totalArray = {"BWM": {"1Seris": ["118d", "120d"], "2Seris": ["m2", "220d"]},
              "Audi": {"A4": ["a4 tsfi", "a4tdi"], "A6": ["a4 tsfi", "a4tdi"]}}

totalList = list(totalArray.values())
totalList2 = list(totalList[0].values())
print(totalList2[0][0])
```

I want to get value `"118d"` by use `"totalList2[0][0]"`

I tried. it was receive the ramdom value.

like something. It was change value 118d, m2, a4 tsfi when it start again

I want to get only "118d" by using the position number

How can i do that?

or

Have have ever know another method?

I want to use map at for loop

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. So you will be unable to get values by index

Comment: Be sure to check the accepted answer at the question linked in the selected duplicate: [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)